# Como ecoar o valor de uma variável a partir do resultado da query

Tags: php, mysql, json, query, variáveis

Para automatizar o meu processo de gerar um *JSON*, eu salvo o nome da variável no banco de dados (Ex: `$teste_value_1`).

No meu *arquivo.php* eu tenho o valor dessa variável, por exemplo `$teste_value_1 = "Isso é um teste";`.

Depois eu faço uma *query* para ecoar essa variável, porém, ao invés dele me retornar o valor  da variável prevista anteriormente no PHP ("Isso é um teste"), ele sempre retorna sem interpretar a variável, apenas como texto ("$teste_value_1").

Abaixo a minha estrutura de dados para entender melhor o processo:

**Tabela: attributes**

```
id_attribute |  attribue_string | attribute_value
1            |  teste_string_1  | $teste_value_1
2            | teste_string_2   | $teste_value_2
```

**Variáveis:**

```
$teste_value_1 = "Isso é um teste";
$teste_value_2 = "Esse é outro teste";
```

**Query:**

```
    $query_array = mysqli_query($connect,"
                    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{id:', a.attribute_string, ',value_name:', a.attribute_value, '}') SEPARATOR ', ') AS concat
                    FROM rel_categories_attributes AS rca
                    INNER JOIN categories AS c ON c.id_category = rca.categories_id_category
                    INNER JOIN attributes AS a ON a.id_attribute = rca.attributes_id_attribute
                    WHERE id_category = '{$id_category}'
                    ");
WHILE ($reg_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($query_array)){

echo $teste_query = $reg_cat["concat"] . ",";
```

**Resultado:**

```
{id:teste_string_1,value_name:$teste_value_1},
{id:teste_string_2,value_name:$teste_value_2},
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
{id:teste_string_1,value_name:Isso é um teste},
{id:teste_string_2,value_name:Isso é outro teste},
```

Comment: Talvez fosse mais viável salvar o json diretamente no banco.
Salvar no nome da variável php não vai funcionar. O php interpola a variável escrita no arquivo sob algumas condições. Uma string contendo a variável não será interpretada assim.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso através de um método chamado *gambiarra*. Com esse método você pode chamar a função `get_defined_vars()` e ela irá retornar todas as variáveis declaradas. Assim você pode buscar e substituir o valor `$nome_da_variavel` no valor retornado pelo banco de dados.

**Segue exemplo comentado:**

```
<?php

$teste_value_1 = "###########";
$teste_value_2 = "***********";

$text = '{id:"teste_string_1",value_name:"$teste_value_1"}, {id:"teste_string_2",value_name:"$teste_value_2"}';

/* Percorre todas as variáveis declaradas. */
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $variable => $value) {

    /* Verifica se o valor da variável é do tipo String */
    if (is_string($value)) {

        /* Realiza a busca e substituição */
        $text = str_replace(
                "\${$variable}",
                $value,
                $text
            );
    }
}

echo $text;
```

> **Obs.**: Isso não é o recomendado, mas, no seu caso, vai funcionar. O ideal é que você pudesse salvar o conteúdo no DB.

Caso você saiba o nome das variáveis e caso elas não mudem o nome, basta utilizar apenas o `str_replace`, por exemplo:

```
$text = str_replace('$teste_value_1', $teste_value_1, $text);
$text = str_replace('$teste_value_2', $teste_value_2, $text);

echo $text;
```